# Small touch screen that works under frosted glass or plastic

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen, touch-panel

I’m trying to build a device with an rpi 3b+ with a touch screen that looks something like the nest thermostat e. Is it possible to have a touchscreen behind frosted glass or can anyone let me know how nest does it on their device. I’m a noob so any help would be awesome. Thank you[image: Nest thermostat e]

Comment: Hi! This question is a bit broad. You need into how "touch sensing"  works; it's not hard to find out the keywords there, and you'll find plenty of development boards that allow you to do exactly these kinds of things.

Comment: Would that work the same way as a touch screen does (recognize gestures and so). Like i mentioned, I’m quite a noob at electronics

Comment: your post says nothing about recognizing gestures

Comment: also, the gesture recognition is not a function of the touch screen, but a functionality implemented by the software that interprets the values coming out of the touchscreen.

Comment: Ah, so basically the driver that’s installed on whatever os thats running on the Rpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a touchscreen behind frosted glass?

Yes.  I can think of at least two touchscreen technologies that would work just fine behind frosted glass.

The technology you probably *don't* want to consider uses IR emitters and receivers at opposite sides of the screen, to detect a finger occluding the light.  This is good for giant displays that you walk up to and interact with.

The technology that you probably *do* want to consider is capacitive touch screen.  This is how smart phone touch screens work.  Smart phone touch screens are faced with glass in the first place, and in the second place they work just fine from behind a 3rd-party screen protector.  Electrically, frosted glass is going to look just like regular glass.

So -- there you go.

If you want actual frosted glass this is going to be difficult to prototype and source, because the glass on touch screens is tempered, and I'm almost certain that tempered glass will break if you try to frost it (or un-frost when you temper it).  So you pretty much can't prototype it without getting the right piece of frosted glass made, and to source it you need a manufacturer willing to make frosted tempered glass -- if that's even a thing.

If you just want a surface that *looks* like frosted glass, then you probably want to overlay the screen with a layer of translucent plastic, possibly followed by a layer of tempered glass for protection.  This should be easy to prototype, and not too difficult to talk a screen manufacturer into, if it's not already a standard option.

Comment: or, just software-wise apply a frosted effect to the graphics you display. 'tad cheaper.

Comment: T'oh!  Real frosted may look better -- but your way is lots cheaper.

Comment: I was thinking of using a surface that looks frosted. Did some more research turns out the nest thermostat e’s screen is not actually a touch screen . Very insightful answers however. Thanks a lot

Comment: Any outward-facing frosted surface will pick up grease from fingers.  On a finely frosted surface, this grease fills in the pits of the frosting and makes it go shiny.  On a touch screen, this means that the most commonly touched areas will be shiny dots (or streaks).  It'll be a housekeeping nightmare for someone, and a security one if it's a touch screen.  Even on a non-touch device, if you don't want this to happen you need to be very careful of the texture.